# ifelse | Mismatch

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

My objective is to compare elements in two vectors.

Here's my first Tibble:

```
Post_Rev
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Fiscal.Quarter.ID        Rev
       <S3: yearqtr>      <dbl>
1            2014 Q1 3889692022
2            2014 Q2 3763028239
3            2014 Q3 4092263526
4            2014 Q4 4865950809
5            2015 Q1 4015879019
6            2015 Q2 4112382310
7            2015 Q3 4247783642
8            2015 Q4 5040074056
9            2016 Q1 4100946981
10           2016 Q2 4021051564
11           2016 Q3 4373665674
12           2016 Q4 5064779447
```

Here's my second vector:

```
Total_Rev
 [1] 3889692022 3763028239 4092263526 4865950809 4015879019 4112382310 4247783642 5040074056
 [9] 4100946981 4021051564 4373665674 5064779447
```

As we can see, the two vectors i.e. Rev in Post_Rev and Total_Rev are equal.
I will also show you class type.

```
class(Post_Rev$Rev)
[1] "numeric"

class(Total_Rev)
[1] "numeric"
```

However, when I run ifelse, it throws "unequal rows" for some rows:

```
ifelse(Post_Rev$Rev != Total_Rev,TRUE,FALSE)
 [1] FALSE  **TRUE** FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE  TRUE** FALSE FALSE
```

What could be the reason? Is there anyway I can find out about the reason? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

I tried Wickham's if_else function:

```
if_else(Post_Rev$Rev != Total_Rev,TRUE,FALSE)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I got the same result. I am unsure why this is happening.

---

Adding dput():

```
dput(Post_Rev)
structure(list(Fiscal.Quarter.ID = structure(c(2014, 2014.25, 
2014.5, 2014.75, 2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 2016, 2016.25, 
2016.5, 2016.75), class = "yearqtr"), Rev = c(3889692022.46776, 
3763028239.33219, 4092263526.07502, 4865950809.37372, 4015879019.37871, 
4112382310.2044, 4247783641.70853, 5040074055.98503, 4100946980.66123, 
4021051564.10049, 4373665674.01029, 5064779446.86354)), .Names = c("Fiscal.Quarter.ID", 
"Rev"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

dput(Total_Rev)
c(3889692022.46776, 3763028239.33219, 4092263526.07502, 4865950809.37372, 
4015879019.37871, 4112382310.2044, 4247783641.70853, 5040074055.98503, 
4100946980.66123, 4021051564.10049, 4373665674.01029, 5064779446.86354
```

Comment: "As we can see, the two vectors i.e. Rev in Post_Rev and Total_Rev are equal." The first rule of comparing numbers with computers is to not mistake what you see _printed on the screen_ with what the _value actually is_. Double check the ones that `ifelse` is saying aren't equal with `all.equal()`.

Comment: (also, `ifelse` is superfluous, as `==` and `!=` are already vectorized)

Comment: Joran, Thanks so much for your help. When I ran  all.equal(Post_Rev$Rev,Total_Rev), I got "[1] TRUE" which means the arrays are equal. Could you please explain why ifelse didn't say the numbers are equal in the above case? I am curious. I'm a beginner and have recently started programming in R. So, I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I can't do much more unless you add the output of `dput()` on both `Post_Rev` and `Total_Rev` to your question.

Comment: Try doing this, as both values are numeric, subtract them and if the result is 0 then true else false

Comment: It's a FAQ, Jack. Numeric values are not displayed to their full level of precision.

Comment: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html (R FAQ 7.31)

Comment: @Joran, I added dput() above.

Comment: Amusingly, the data structures you posted do not exhibit the problematic behavior your question is premised on. (Everything reports that they are all equal.) So I _definitely_ can't help under these circumstances. :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of answering this question. r2evans and 42 are spot on:

When we subtract the numbers, we see that there is a difference in the numbers.

```
Post_Rev$Rev-Total_Rev
 [1]  0.000000e+00 -4.768372e-07  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
 [7]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 -4.768372e-07 -4.768372e-07  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```